# Role not being awarded to user via role name tracking

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I have the following code:

```js
let role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(rolename => rolename.name === toString(rankname))

message.member.roles.add(role).catch(error => {
  console.log("Error: " + error)
})
```

I am getting the following error:
[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yMWFk.png)

Any help would be appreciated, thanks. :)

FYI: Rankname is a string returned by a promise function.

Comment: Why don't you check what the value of `role` is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to read a role from cache, but it is probably not in it, so role is `undefined`, use the `RoleManager.resolve()` function instead:

```
let role = message.guild.roles.resolve(toString(rankname))
```

note that using a Snowflake instead of a name would be better, if you go from the message.author.roles to get the name of the role you can probably use the id instead.